# get post Id in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plugin in wordpress. And I am trying to get the post id when I click the publish button on the `add new post`. And now, I get an internal error(500) when I use the get post function.

I am using`_POST['post']` now, but how can I use the wordpress function to get the post id?

Here is my code:

```
//require the php
require_once( FACEBOOK_API_PLUGIN_DIR . 'js/databaseConnection.php' );
```

Code on databaseConnection.php:

```
function get_post()
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
        return $thePostID;
    }


function try_insert($post_id)
{
    $test02 = 333243;
    $test03 = 222;
     $link = @mysqli_connect(
                'localhost',
                'root',
                '',
                'wordpress'
          ) or die("connection failed");

             $sql = "INSERT INTO post_data02 (post_id, condition_code) VALUES ('$post_id','$test03')";

            if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link -> error;
            }
     $link->close();
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'try_insert', get_post());
```

Also, when I disable the `get_post()` function I error will be gone. What am I doing wrong?

thanks,

Comment: Why is this tagged `Javascript`?

Comment: I made a tinymce on the `add new post` using `Javascript`, and this `php` will return the data to the `js`

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `get_post` at all and you are using the [publish_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) hook and [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function incorrectly.

Additionally, have a look at the [WPDB class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/). If your table is in the same database and schema as your WordPress tables you don't need to use mysqli_connect - WordPress has already connected to the database for you!

Note also that you should NEVER pass values into a string to be used as part of an SQL statement! This is a MASSIVE security risk! ALWAYS use [prepared statements and parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (WPDB provides this as well).

Try this:

```php
function try_insert($post_id, $post)
{
    // Pull in the global WPDB variable WordPress creates
    global $wpdb;

    $test02 = 333243;
    $test03 = 222;

    /*
     * Insert record into the table "post_data02" with the values:
     *   "post_id" => The ID in $post_id passed by WordPress,
     *   "condition_code" => The number in $test03 (currently 222)
    */
    $insert = $wpdb->insert( 'post_data02',
        [ 'post_id' => $post_id, 'condition_code' => $test03 ],
        [ '%d',                  '%d' ]
    );

    if( $insert !== false ) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link -> error;
    }

}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'try_insert', 10, 2);
```

Please re-read the links I provided above as they provide excellent examples and show you how to use the functions, methods, hooks, etc.

Comment: If I need to pass the parameter to the method, Is it doing like this?
`function pass($id, $name, $address){...` -> `add_action( 'publish_post', 'pass', 10, 3);` -> `do_action('pass', 01, 'john', 'island');`   
Like this?

Comment: You can either set it as global scope
    `$myVar = 1;
    function try_insert($post_id, $post) {
        global $myVar;
        ...
    }
    add_action( 'publish_post', 'try_insert', 10, 2);`

Comment: or use a lambda function with "use":
`$myVar = 1; add_action( 'publish_post', function($post_id, $post) use ($myVar) { ...
}, 10, 2);`